# Configuring Hibernate to use JPA-style configuration without going into EE

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, ejb

I am in the process of troubleshooting a recent translation of EJB code to native Hibernate code (painful process, since EJB spoiled me so much with its convenience).

One thing I find troublesome is that Hibernate keeps its entity declarations in a hbm.xml file and then the configurations in separate files. While this isn't necessarily a big issue, the Netbeans wizard doesn't really let the developer to just click a button, detect, all the entities on the fly, and update the configuration file.

With persistence.xml, however, I can do that easily by just adding the classes and forget about it. Another good thing is that persistence.xml stores pretty much everything needed for the ORM aside from the class-specific annotations (which I am keeping).

With that said, is there any way for me to have Hibernate to (1) stay off EE and (2) use persistence.xml to get the connection, mapping, etc?

Also, a related question - CriteriaQuery is apparently a Java EE thing. One thing I really like about using EJB is that there are strong compile-time contraints. For instance, I can put ClassName_.myAttribute directly as a parameter in a CriteriaQuery, whereas if I use the Hibernate native "Criteria" object, I have to use "my_attribute" instead, which is not subjected to compile time integrity checks (Note: ClassName_.myAttribute maps to "my_attribute" on the table).

So is there anyway to keep that compile-time integrity?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you better ask two questions instead of askint two in one post.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was bending the rules a bit there. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate EntityManager can be used outside of a Java EE container. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html_single/#architecture-javase.

Moreover, even with the Hibernate native API, since you're using annotations, you don't need any hbm.xml file. Just a central Hibernate config file listing the entities and some Hibernate properties.

Comment: Thanks. I found out I got a bit confused - yes, annotations replace need of mapping files. However, one thing I noticed with my Netbeans Maven project is that the hibernate.cfg.xml wizard doesn't let me choose or automatically detect entity classes (unlike the persistence.xml wizard), which led me to this misconception. However, even with that aside, it's still annoying that I have to manually keep track of entity classes. Are there better solutions? Also, I did come across that paragraph you cited... (cont)

Comment: ... and noted that " JTA transactions" and "persistence context propagation" are not supported in Java SE so that's probably the line is drawn. However, I don't really understand what is "persistence context propagation" and the pages I googled are not helpful descriptions.

Comment: Regarding the first problem, well, just remember to add the entity to the list each one you create one. Regarding the second one, it means that you can't expect to have the EM injected in various components, and get the right persistence context in all these depending on the current transaction. But you may use Spring to get all this in a non-JEE environment.

Comment: So that means CriteriaQuery is actually not part of EE? And so all I need is to make a Singleton class that has generates EntityManager to get around the problem? My current JPA code basically just involves getting EMs from a Singleton and do CriteriaQueries with them.

Comment: Criteria queries are part of the JPA API. And JPA is available for JEE and for JSE.